ServiceM8: Intermittent issue with apartment / unit number not being returned
When retrieving geo_locations via the SM8 api we are getting inconsistent responses where addresses that contain a '/' in them are not always returning the prefix.
So for example: "1/123 fake st" sometimes returns "geo_number=123" and other times it returns "geo_number=1/123"... there seems to be no rhyme or reason to the results.
Here is a screenshot of the returned geoLocation response:

and here it is displayed in a sm8 job correctly:

and here's the job address (returned by the same api call but as a single string)

Is this a know issue? And are there any ideas how to solve this? (without needing to involve Google API's).
(One theory I had is that SM8 are running multiple servers and some of them are running different code; as it looks like a classic example of when you use queue's and the worker doesn't get restarted after code has been deployed and continues running the previous version of the app.. but just a theory)
